# Using FilterType:=xlValueIsGreaterThan in Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a table that looks like this

```
Name    Order Amount    Location
Grace       120000       new jersey
Tom         200000       baltimore
Rick       5000000       hyderabad
Hari        600000       denver
Raj        4000000       Delhi
Victoria    300000       New York
```

I created a pivot with all 3 fields but I cannot successfully use the 
PivotFilters.Add FilterType:=xlValueIsGreaterThan

option successfully...what I wrong with my code?

```
 Sub addFields()
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
'First row field
  With .PivotFields("Name")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
  End With

 'Report Filter field
 With .PivotFields("Location")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
  .Position = 1
   End With

  'Order Amount or numerical data  in the Values field
   .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Order Amount"), _
   "Sum of Amount", xlSum
   End With


 With .PivotFields("Sum of Amount").PivotFilters.Add    filterType:=xlValueIsGreaterThan  DataField :="Sum of Amount" value1:=4000000




 End With

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

test this in place of your last with statement

```
with .PivotFields("Name").PivotFilters.Add2 _
    Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Order Amount"), Value1:=4000000
```